# Prevent keyboard from resigning after "return" was triggered?

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, dismiss

my question is kind of straightforward and pretty much the opposite of what most people try to achieve:

How can I prevent the keyboard from disappearing when the 'return' / 'done' button is pressed?

Thanks a lot!
Regards,
wasabi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a UITextFieldDelegate, and override the textfieldShouldReturn: method.  If you return NO from this method, the keyboard will not disappear.

And of course, link up your delegate to the textField